# xml2js parsed result without attributes

Tags: javascript, xml2js

Using [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js), what is the way to parse XML and return a result without the XML attributes?

E.g., for the input

```xml
<foo type="attr">bar</completion_date>
```

I wish to get

```json
"foo": "Bar"
```

Rather than

```json
"foo": {
  "_": "bar",
  "$": {
    "type": "attr"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set option `ignoreAttrs: true` in your `Parser` object. The it will ignore all XML attributes. Look at the [options section](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#options) in the documantation for referance.